# osclass - how do i list only some cities and areas located in the city in the location list?

Tags: php, osclass

is there any way in osclass using which I can add a list of new cities and area names under that city.

In the back-end admin panel I can see that country = 'United States' > States = 'States of US' > City = 'City list of each state'

Our site is more concentrated towards only Arizona>Phoenix so for that do I have to delete all the current locations and then start adding each city of Arizona manually.

Is there a way to just disable all the other states of US and only allow the Arizona state to be listed and the cities in it?

Comment: just put one flag of `active/inactive` in your `db-table`... get the `id value of arizona` and fire one query to inactive other remaining in the table..

Answer (score 1):

i would delete all regions and then just add arizona as region and list the cities inside it, i would also delete the country and region from search